# How to access network shares?

Tags: file-sharing, cifs

I am using intranet using run command in Windows by directly typing the intranet address like `\172.16.0.11` and pressing enter. Then a tab opens for username and password. In Ubuntu 12.04 how can I open internet?

Comment: Open Firefox? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish... If you're saying you run a particular command to *connect* to the internet, please specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Dash>Firefox. You should see a web browser. Type in `172.16.0.11` and press enter. Type in a username and a password and you should be able to access your intranet like on Windows. If your intranet is a file server, go to Nautilus,click File, then Connect to Server and in the Server field type in `172.16.0.11`. The server type should be Samba, depending on your server. It might be FTP too, so if the above method doesn't work try that. The Port and Folder fields should be empty. then click Connect.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu open Firefox, in the address bar type the URL `http://172.16.0.11`. If you are prompted to provide a username and password this is a feature of the site. If you are meant to access it this information should be provided by your system admin.